# Randomly selecting from an array a desired amount of times

Tags: python, arrays

For some reason, this code below doesn't select from the array the desired amount of times from the TimesRun variable. I was just trying to do a Monty hall simulation for fun but no clue what I'm doing.

```
import random

def Doors():
    
    doors = ["Goat","Goat1","Car"]
    selection = doors[random.randint(0,2)]
    return selection

i = 0
goat = 0
goat1 = 0
car = 0

TimesRun = input("How many times would you like to simulate this problem\n")
while i < int(TimesRun):
        Doors()
        if Doors() == "Goat":
            goat += 1
        elif Doors() == "Goat1":
            goat1 += 1
        elif Doors() == "Car":
            car += 1
        i += 1
    
print("Goat: " + str(goat) + "\nCar: " + str(car) + "\nGoat1: " + str(goat1))
print(goat + car + goat1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call `Doors()` you get a new random result -- so call it once, and assign that result to a variable in order to do your comparisons.

```
import random

def Doors():
    return random.choice(["Goat","Goat1","Car"])

goat = 0
goat1 = 0
car = 0

TimesRun = input("How many times would you like to simulate this problem\n")
for _ in range(int(TimesRun)):
    door = Doors()
    if door == "Goat":
        goat += 1
    elif door == "Goat1":
        goat1 += 1
    elif door == "Car":
        car += 1
    
print(f"Goat: {goat}\nCar: {car}\nGoat1: {goat1}")
print(goat + car + goat1 )
```

You can shorten the code quite a bit by using a `Counter` instead of three named variables and a bunch of `if`s:

```
import collections
import random

times = int(input("How many times would you like to simulate this problem\n"))
choices = collections.Counter(random.choice(
    ["Goat", "Goat1", "Car"]
) for _ in range(times))

print("\n".join(f"{door}: {count}" for door, count in choices.items()))
print(sum(choices.values()))
```

Comment: `random.choices` would make it even shorter.